# Copy file from url with https connection in android

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in this and I can't copy a file from a url below https connection with authentication. I got to authenticate, and trust the host. This file in url is a little big file. It copies a piece but not all content in file,  always copy the same piece. Any idea what could be?

I try to copy the file after getting inputStream from connection. As follows:

```
    boolean result=false;
    ....
    https.connect();
    InputStream in=https.getInputStream();
    File f=new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+File.separator+"file.json");
    RandomAccessFile out=new RandomAccessFile(f,"rw");
    int numberOfBytesWritten=0;
    try {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
      int count;
      while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        numberOfBytesWritten += count;
      }
      out.close();
      in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    if(bytes==0) result=false;
    else result=true;

    if(result) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DOWNLOADED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FAILED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Your buffer is probably not big enough.

Comment: Honestly, I'd just use `commons-io` for this kind of thing and copy the input stream to an output stream with `IOUtils.copy(is, os)`.

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce that's it very useful!